# One Liner sed date string to unixtime

Tags: sed, date

I'm running the following command:

```
cat /tmp/myfile.log | sed -n -e 's/^.*Expire: //p'
```

Which returns the following string

```
04-nov-2018
```

I then want to run that string through the following command:

```
date -d '04-nov-2018' + "%s"
```

that will return the unixtime:

```
1541304000
```

How do I run that in a single command line?

Comment: `date -d "$(sed -n .... /tmp/myfile)" + "%s"`?

Comment: sweet! answer it and I'll mark closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a command within a `$( )`, so that you can directly say:

```
date -d "$(command)" + "%s"
```

In your case:

```
date -d "$(sed -n -e 's/^.*Expire: //p' /tmp/myfile.log)" + "%s"
```

Note also I am saying `sed '...' file` instead of `cat file | sed '...'`, since `sed` can directly read from the file.

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to have the GNU implementation of `date`, you can do:

```
</tmp/myfile.log sed -n 's/^.*Expire: //p' | date -f - +%s
```

With GNU `sed` (and still GNU `date`), you can also do:

```
</tmp/myfile.log sed -n 's/^.*Expire: /date +%s -d/ep'
```

(assuming POSIXLY_CORRECT is not in the environment)

But beware that it amounts to a command injection vulnerability if you can't guarantee that what's after any `Expire:` tag is not that date in that format. Albeit shorter, it's also a lot less efficient than the above as it runs one shell and one `date` command for each matching line (and retrieves its output through a pipe, to later output it again on stdout).

On non-GNU systems, you could use `perl`:

```
</tmp/myfile.log perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
  print Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d-%b-%Y")->epoch if /Expire: (\S+)/'
```

Or use the date parsing capability of your shell if using advanced ones like `zsh` (`strftime -r` builtin) or `ksh93` (`printf %T`).

Answer (score 1):

Use substitution:

```
date -d "`cat /tmp/myfile.log | sed -n -e 's/^.*Expire: //p'`" + "%s"
```

Surrounding your first command with `` ` `` allows you to use its output as part of another command. Surrounding this in turn with `"` helps to prevent against complications if the output of the first command happens to contain spaces or special characters.